# Wrong JSON result in Android

Tags: android, json

I need to get listview json from php server.having problem with my api,this is my api link

```
http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_exe_newenq.php?exeId=2
```

In my browser i got proper response. this same url in android asyn task i am getting error response.

```
{"success":"0","message":"New enquiry not found ."}
```

may be this will be logicless question but i could not find the mistake.Is this Api problem or app problem?what i am doing wrong?

this is my code

```
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
              // Building Parameters
              List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

              UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
              HashMap<String, String> user = userFunctions.getExinfo(EnquiryActivity.this);

             String userid1 = user.get("exid");
               System.out.println(userid1);


              final String URL_LIST1 = "http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_exe_newenq.php?exeId=2";


                 System.out.println(URL_LIST1);  
              JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();    

              JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_LIST1, get, params);
              System.out.println(json);
```

getJSONFROmUrl method

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url,String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);           
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            return null;

        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Comment: Post the code, what you mean by error response?

Comment: @RemeesMSyde {"success":"0","message":"New enquiry not found ."} this is my response in log

Comment: The url u given above is working fine, check the value "params" you used is correct, also post some more code, what is 'get' , 'params' and JSONParser class also.

Comment: I tried other urls .all other urls working fine.get means GET method

Comment: post getJSONFromUrl method code also

Comment: posted  getJSONFromUrl method

Comment: Try my answer below and replay me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a map of params, and your getJSONfromUrl appends a "?" to your URL followed by those parameters. In your particular case however, the params are empty, and you actually supplied the query parameters already in the url string. 
This means that the URL you're actually getting is 
http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_exe_newenq.php?exeId=2?

Note the trailing question mark. If you open this URL in your browser you will get the same error response.

Solution would be to either

1. remove the exeId param from the URL and instead pass it as part of the param map and let getJSONfromUrl append it
2. Stop passing params completely and assume URL is complete already (which it is in your case)
3. Add a check to see if the param map is empty before adding any query to the URL (this should be done in any case)

   `if (params.size() > 0) {
       String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
       url += "?" + paramString;
   }`

Note also that you should use `String.equals()` rather than == to compare your "GET", "POST" etc strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `JSONParser` class `GET` like this.

```
           else if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                // url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
```

> The reason is unwanted empty "params" passed through your URL, no need
> to pass the "params" if not necessary.
>
> If "params" is null,It will change your url like below.
>
> http://staging.homeneedsonline.com/ws/ws_exe_newenq.php?exeId=2?
>
> This url gave that error response to you.

So avoid appending "params" in the url.

Comment: I added a somewhat similar answer now, because I didn't see your response at the time. Sorry about that. My answer does have some extra info though so I won't throw it away.

Comment: Its OK, no probs dude.

Comment: This is not the feedback, this is the right answer and first answer is mine. So you have to accept my answer. Anyway its ok for me, can you please give me a +1.